# copy only changed text to clipboard

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a question about a problem i need do solve.
I have a word doc, on which i want to run a search and replace query.
But i dont want to change the actual text, i want to put the changed text
in the clipboard and leave the actual one unchanged.

```vb
Sub SearchAndReplace()

    ' marks all bold words,italic words, underlined
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True
    Selection.Find.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "[test]^&[/test]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain why you want to put multiple items in the clipboard.  There may be an easier way to achieve what you want.  At the moment you are just telling us about the technique you think you should use and not the problem you wish to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Cautious: 
I guess there are better ways to achieve what you want to do as this is not proper coding. (Also as the clipboard only has a limit of 24 items), but for the sake of making your code works, here is my answer:

To copy the text in the clipboard instead of replacing it, you can just use the `.copy` method.

If you replace your line:

```
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

by

```
Dim iCount As Long 

    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Copy

Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And iCount < 1000
    iCount = iCount + 1

    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Copy
Loop
```

it should work.

The code is simply copying the item found after each search. 
`Selection.Find.Execute` searches the next itteration of the search every time it appears in the code.

Once there are no search found anymore (or there are too many searches), the loop will stop.